# ruby on rails git permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, macos, ssh

I am following [this](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan) guide to set ruby on rails environment on my Mac El Captain.

I followed upto installing homebrew, ruby latest version 2.2.3 with rbenv. Now, I was setting up git.

Followed up first few commands

```
git config --global color.ui true
git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"
git config --global user.email "YOUR@EMAIL.com"
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "YOUR@EMAIL.com"
```

Now, I have been asked to save the generated key. I saved it to `~` directory with a name `file`. I have now two files namely `file` and `file.pub`.

I went to [this](https://github.com/settings/ssh) link to copy ssh key. I clicked on *Add SSH key* option there. Named the key *ROR SSH Key*.

The key in `file.pub` looks like

ssh-rss asfjasfhjalsfdhaskfdhalsdfsdf\asdf\as\dg\sa\fasdfas\f\asdf---so on random numbers---adfasdfasfa myemail@gmail.com

and I pasted the key there in github and saved the key.

Then, I went back to terminal and typed the below command.

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

but I didn't received any message saying "*Hi excid3! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.*"

I got a message saying

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.251.130)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6sdfgdfgsdfgGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.251.130' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Here above I have change few characters in SHA256 key. Just for security. Also, I have changed IP address a little bit for the same. But, the idea behind it is same.

Please guide me what's wrong. Thanks.

Comment: try to type `ssh-add` on terminal and push again

Comment: @matanco can you re-write the complete command that I needed to write in terminal?

Comment: this is the command: `ssh-add` then try again what you did.

Comment: @matanco I typed `ssh-add` in terminal and then again tried `ssh -T git@github.com`. I get permission denied(public key)

Comment: I'd recommend reading how the ssh keys work, where they're stored by default. By using non-default values you've made a lot of extra work for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `ssh` will look in the `~/.ssh` folder for your private keys. Since you saved it in `~` instead, it can't find it.

You can either:

1. Move the `file` and `file.pub` files into `~/.ssh` and rename to `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, as OS X will automatically use those files for any `ssh` command (if you hadn't manually entered a filename, this is where `ssh-keygen` would have saved them).
2. Use the `ssh-add -K file` command to permanently add your key to the OS X Keychain.

Note that [GitHub's own instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) say they "strongly suggest keeping the default settings" instead of saving the private/public key somewhere else.